# have a number like 000x-000yy that counts the number of invoices issued each month and year so that it resets after each month and year

Tags: ms-access

Suppose a number Order_No counts the number of invoices submitted.
The date an invoice is issued has the structure "yyyy-mm-dd"

Each form has the new number generated by:
looking at the maximum order number of the entry with the same month to generate x (000x-00yy), and looking at the maximum order number of the entry with the same year to generate yy

Please help I really appreciate it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set custom ID field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297965/how-to-set-custom-id-field). Generating a custom unique identifier is a common topic. Do research and when you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35947449/2144390