# Sequential Numbers in MS Access using along the 'Year' and 'Year Day Count' from a field

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get MS Access to create auto sequence numbers to visiting patients of a clinic, using along two-digit 'year' and ‘day count of year’ and three digit sequential number.
e.g. (23) & (001 – 365) & (001 – 999)
in combination make eight-digit sequence number for a particular date.
Like, assign ‘23031012’ to the twelfth visitor patient on 31st Jan 2023.

For this I made a table ‘VisitList_T’ having fields
•   VisitID         (auto-number)
•   YearStartDate           =”03-Jan-2023” (plz suggest any other input method through form)
•   VisitDate       Date(), (to get current day count by calculation)
•   VisitTime       Time()
•   VisitNumber     (??? the required sequence number ???)
•   Pt_Name_ID      ID or name of visiting patient

Then I created a query to get ‘year day count’ and used ”YD_Count: ([VisitDate]-[YearStartDate]+1)”

Please help to get the required result. Is it possible to get this result in the table ‘VisitList_T’ field ‘VisitNumber’

I am not able to code at all, and could not find any information on this so it might not even be possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generating custom unique identifier is a common topic. Need VBA to produce the sequential number if you don't want to rely on autonumber.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set custom ID field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297965/how-to-set-custom-id-field)

Answer (score 0):

The next visit number could be found with this expression in the ControlSource for a textbox:

```
=(Format(Date(), "yy") & Right("00" & Format(Date(), "y"), 3)) * 1000 + DCount("*","[VisitList_T]", "[VisitNumber] \ 1000 = " & Format(Date(), "yy") & Right("00" & Format(Date(), "y"), 3) & "") + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern Gustav, 
but would you please revisit this suggestion? 
it is stuck to the answer "23004001" on each data entry.

Comment: You must add the retrieved number to the table before pulling the next.

Comment: Plz, elaborate 'retrieved number'.
I am adding data to 'Pt_Name_ID' the only available field for this purpose. 
And used all three means 'Table', 'Query' and form.
each time it gives 23004001 in the 'Visit number, text box.

Comment: Access is showing an Error message "Circular reference" by the text box.

Comment: Then rename the textbox. Also, you wrote _VisitNumber (??? the required sequence number ???)_. If this is not the table field, replace that with the actual table field (`Pt_Name_ID`?)

Comment: it is still not working :( 
Well, Thank you for your concern and time.
I think. I am not capable enough to get the results out of this expression.