# MS Access Forms autofill next record +1

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to automatically fill a text box on a form with the previous record's entry, plus 1, until that entry is manually changed? I have a form to enter catalog numbers (short text), which are alphanumeric "numbers" formatted as 1XX11.001. The 1XX11 is the "context number" for the last three digits. I would like to have the next record be" 1XX11.002,1XX11.003, and so on.

I've tried formatting a button with the following code: Nz(DMax("right([CATALOG_NUMBER],3)", "[TABLE_1]"),0)+1

However, DMax doesn't seem to work here since the last three digits of the catalog number restart at 001 when the context number 1XX11 changes to 1XX12, etc. Instead, the value DMax returns is the maximum last three digits in the entire field (CATALOG_NUMBER)+1.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set custom ID field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297965/how-to-set-custom-id-field)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim Prefix As String
    Dim Number As Integer

    Prefix = "1XX11"
    Number = DMax("CATALOG_NUMBER", "YourTable", "CATALOG_NUMBER Like '" & Prefix & "*'") + 1
    Me!CATALOG_NUMBER.Value = Prefix & Format(Number, "000")

End Sub
```